# What does %||% in R do?

Tags: r

Apologies if this has been asked before, but it's hard to search for this as it's in characters.  Regardless, what does `%||%` do in R?  I see it in some code I am working on, and yet I cannot understand it.  I've tried some things:

```
num <- c(1,2,3)
1 %||% num
[1] 1
num %||% 3
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Note that `%||%` it not a base R function. It may come from a package you are using. What code are you looking at? What packages do you have loaded?

Answer (score 0):

It is used for `NULL` check.  By checking the documentation in ?rlang::`%||%`

> If x is NULL, will return y; otherwise returns x.

In the examples showed both cases are not NULL, so it returns the 'x' i.e. the one on the lhs of `%||%`

Using a different example

```
v1 <- NULL
v1 %||% num
#[1] 1 2 3
```